# VBA Macro to Speak in Solidworks

Tags: vba, solidworks

I have a random quote generator from over 100 quotes that pops up in my message box once my macro has completed its task. Can I get the macro to speak the message thats in the messagebox?

I have a macro one of my ex workmates has written that does this in excel using VBA, but I cant get it to work in solidworks.

```
Option Explicit
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swDraw As SldWorks.DrawingDoc
Dim swCustProp As CustomPropertyManager
Dim swView As SldWorks.View

Dim ConfigName As String
Dim i As Long
Dim valOut1 As String
Dim valOut2 As String
Dim resolvedValOut1 As String
Dim resolvedValOut2 As String
Dim PartNo As String
Dim nFileName As String
Dim swDocs As Variant
Dim PDFpath As String
Dim currpath As String
Dim PartNoDes As String
Dim strquotes(9) As String
Dim lngIndex As Long

Sub main()

strquotes(1) = "Charge like a wounded bull."
strquotes(2) = "Colder than a coal miner's bum."
strquotes(3) = "Tighter than a fish's asshole, and that's watertight."
strquotes(4) = "Is the pope catholic?"
strquotes(5) = "FINE = fucking insecure neurotic and emotional."
strquotes(6) = "I think that's a boy on a man's mission."
strquotes(7) = "Don't stick your finger where you wouldn't stick your dick."
strquotes(8) = "After all's said and done there's more said than done."
strquotes(9) = "Stick to it like shit on a wool blanket."

lngIndex = Int((9 - 0 + 1) * Rnd + 0)

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks

Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc

If swModel.GetType = swDocDRAWING Then

Set swDraw = swApp.ActiveDoc
Set swView = swDraw.GetFirstView
Set swView = swView.GetNextView
Set swModel = swView.ReferencedDocument

currpath = Left(swDraw.GetPathName, InStrRev(swDraw.GetPathName, "\"))
PDFpath = currpath & "PDF"

If Dir(PDFpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir PDFpath


            If swModel.GetType = swDocPART Then
                    PartNoDes = Mid(swDraw.GetPathName, InStrRev(swDraw.GetPathName, "\") + 1)
                    PartNoDes = Right(PartNoDes, Len(PartNoDes) - 14)
                    PartNoDes = Left(PartNoDes, Len(PartNoDes) - 7)
                    PartNo = Mid(swModel.GetPathName, InStrRev(swModel.GetPathName, "\") + 1)
                    PartNo = Left(PartNo, Len(PartNo) - 7)
                    Set swCustProp = swModel.Extension.CustomPropertyManager(swView.ReferencedConfiguration)
                    ConfigName = swView.ReferencedConfiguration
                    swCustProp.Get2 "Description", valOut1, resolvedValOut1
                    swCustProp.Get2 "Revision", valOut2, resolvedValOut2
                    nFileName = PDFpath & "\" & PartNo & "-" & ConfigName & "-" & resolvedValOut2 & " " & PartNoDes
                    swDraw.SaveAs3 nFileName & ".PDF", 0, 0
                    Application.speech.speak (strquotes(lngIndex))
                    MsgBox (PartNo & "-" & ConfigName & "-" & resolvedValOut2 & " " & PartNoDes & ".pdf" & "  Saved in" & vbNewLine & Left(swModel.GetPathName, Len(swModel.GetPathName) - 17) & "PDF" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Lormanism Of The Day :" & vbNewLine & strquotes(lngIndex))

            ElseIf swModel.GetType = swDocASSEMBLY Then
                    PartNoDes = Mid(swDraw.GetPathName, InStrRev(swDraw.GetPathName, "\") + 1)
                    PartNoDes = Right(PartNoDes, Len(PartNoDes) - 11)
                    PartNoDes = Left(PartNoDes, Len(PartNoDes) - 7)
                    PartNo = Mid(swModel.GetPathName, InStrRev(swModel.GetPathName, "\") + 1)
                    PartNo = Left(PartNo, Len(PartNo) - 7)
                    Set swCustProp = swModel.Extension.CustomPropertyManager("")
                    swCustProp.Get2 "Description", valOut1, resolvedValOut1
                    swCustProp.Get2 "Revision", valOut2, resolvedValOut2
                    nFileName = PDFpath & "\" & PartNo & "-" & resolvedValOut2 & " " & PartNoDes
                    swDraw.SaveAs3 nFileName & ".PDF", 0, 0
                    Application.speech.speak (strquotes(lngIndex))
                    MsgBox (PartNo & "-" & resolvedValOut2 & " " & PartNoDes & ".pdf" & "  Saved in" & vbNewLine & Left(swModel.GetPathName, Len(swModel.GetPathName) - 17) & "PDF" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Lormanism Of The Day :" & vbNewLine & strquotes(lngIndex))
            End If

Set swDraw = Nothing

Else: MsgBox "Active document is not a drawing"

End If

End Sub
```

I am looking at the line `application.speech.speak (strquotes(lngIndex))` and I get the following error: `Run-time error '438': Object doesnt support this property or method`

Comment: You could start by posting the code from the excel example and explaining what doesn't work in solidworks (e.g. Compile error, runtime error, no errors but doesn't work as expected, etc.)  Also, any explanation as to what you've tried so far would be helpful.

Comment: Is the quote you get a string? Have a search on `"SAPI.SpVoice"` - works on VBS and so should work in VBA.

Comment: Can you try remove the brackets? So its `Application.Speech.Speak strquotes(lngIndex)`. By the way you left out the index zero in the strquotes array (unless intends to not speak).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, returns True when the text is spoken by computer.

```
Function RobotSpeaking(sText As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    With CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
        .Volume = 100
        .Speak sText
    End With
    RobotSpeaking = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

Comment: You don't need the `Err.Clear` the error number is automatically reset by the `On Error Resume Next` code.  Also, might consider at getting rid of that and implementing a way to handle errors.